# How to convert Seq[Object] to Map[User, Set[String] in Scala

Tags: scala

It's really hard to explain in the title but here's what I want to do.

I'm pretty new to Scala. I have an object `User` which is just a user that two users can be equal given the same user id

```
case class UserCustomFeature(
  hobby: String,
  users: Set[User]
) {}
```

My input is `Seq[UserCustomFeature]` So basically a list of objects of a hobby -> users. For example,

```
[('tv' -> Set('user1', 'user2')),
('swimming' -> Set('user2', 'user3'))]
```

And I want the result to be

```
('user1' -> Set('tv')),
('user2' -> Set('tv', 'swimming')),
('user3' -> Set('swimming'))
```

I have something like this so far but I'm not sure how to group them later

```
userHobbyMap
      .map({
        case (hobby, users) => {
          users.map(user => {
            (user, hobby)
          })
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case class User(id: String)
case class UserCustomFeature(
  hobby: String,
  users: Set[User]
) {}

val input = Seq(
  UserCustomFeature("tv", Set(User("1"), User("2"))),
  UserCustomFeature("swimming", Set(User("2"), User("3")))
)

val output = (for (UserCustomFeature(h, us) <- input; u <- us) yield (u, h))
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2).toSet)

output foreach println
```

Generates output:

```
(User(1),Set(tv))
(User(3),Set(swimming))
(User(2),Set(tv, swimming))
```

Brief explanation:

- `for`-comprehension transposes the sequence of `UserCustomFeature`s into a list of `(user, hobby)` pairs.
- `groupBy` groups hobbies by user (first component)
- The `map(_._2)` drops the redundant user id from grouped pairs
- `toSet` converts the resulting list of hobbies to a set of hobbies